# Installing Genymotion in docker

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, genymotion

Was anyone able to install Genymotion in docker? Please help me with the required steps. Tried googling couldn't find much details.

I tried emulator with WebDriver but it seems to be very slow. Any suggestions in improving this also helps.